# Filter an ee.Dictionary by keys

Tags: google-earth-engine, dictionary

Is there a way to filter an Earth Engine dictionary by keys?

```js
var dict = ee.Dictionary({
  "date": ['2020-10-02', '2020-10-04', '2020-10-02', '2020-10-01'],
  "count": [1, 1, 3, 2],
  "x": [1, 1, 0, 0]
});

keys = ee.List(["date", "x"])

// apply some method to get the same dict but filtered by key name 
ee.Dictionary({
  "date": ['2020-10-02', '2020-10-04', '2020-10-02', '2020-10-01'],
  "x": [1, 1, 0, 0]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary has a `select()` function for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new dictionary from the filtered values. As you already declared the keys you just need 2 more lines to get the filtered dictionnary:

```js
var keys = ee.List(["count", "x"])
var values = keys.map(function(k){return dict.get(k)}
var dict_filtered = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(keys, values)
```